# How do I handle user interaction and sockets events simultaneously?

Tags: c++, sockets, ncurses, event-driven

I am writing this chat program that uses ncurses as the interface. How am I suppose to simultaneously handle the socket file descriptors and user interation? My idea is below. The problem is now the loop only executes once for each button I press. How do I structure my program such that the sockets and user interaction are handled immediately once they are ready? I tried just having my poll include the file descriptors for standard input and output, but that does not work.

```
while(ch = getch()) {
   poll sockets
   loop sockets {
      ...
   }
   switch(ch) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Also as a more general question. How does one typically write programs that handles user interaction and other things going on at once? It seems like there would be a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `nodelay()` on your input screen.

```
nodelay(stdscr,TRUE); // turn off getch() blocking

while(getch() == ERR)
{
    //do other stuff
}
else
    //handle input
```

But chances are you may want to go to threading down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Build up an file descriptor set (FD_SET) that includes STDIN as well as the socket you're trying to read, then use select() on the set.  Something like the following::

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  fd_set fds;
  int fd = open(/* your socket */);
  struct timeval tv;

  FD_ZERO(&fds);
  FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
  FD_SET(fd, &fds);

  while (1) {
     tv.tv_sec = 1; // wait for up to 1 sec
     int retval = select(2, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
     if (retval > 0) {
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds)) 
            // process stdin
        else if (FD_ISSET(fd, &fds))
            // process data from your socket
     } else if (retval == 0) 
        // timeout
     else
        // some error
   }
   exit 0;
}
```

(Note I didn't compile this, but you should get the idea.)

See [fd_set](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set) and [select tutorial](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut)